# Google Maps Activity Error: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted?

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I get this error when I try to intent a new activity (ProfileActivity) or open some request permissions dialog when GoogleMap is displayed.

**Start Activity function**

```
private fun navigateToProfile(view: View){

    val options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this)
    val revealX = (view.x + view.width / 2).toInt()
    val revealY = (view.y + view.height / 2).toInt()
    val intent = Intent(this, ProfileActivity::class.java)
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS
    intent.putExtra(ProfileActivity.EXTRA_CIRCULAR_REVEAL_X, revealX);
    intent.putExtra(ProfileActivity.EXTRA_CIRCULAR_REVEAL_Y, revealY);
    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())
}
```

Basically my app consists of a map and a floating button that opens a profile view, both are defined as activites.

**log**

```
E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
D/ViewRootImpl[ProfileActivity]: changeCanvasOpacity: opaque=false
E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
D/ViewRootImpl[ProfileActivity]: changeCanvasOpacity: opaque=false
E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
D/ViewRootImpl[ProfileActivity]: changeCanvasOpacity: opaque=false
E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
```

I have found that this problem occurs mainly due to opening dialogs or other view components when displaying the map fragment? Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: hi, have you found a fix for this?